# # parameters: 4th order polynomial regression in 5 dimensions

Tags: regression, machine-learning, polynomial

I read that a 4th order polynomial regression in 5 dimensions amounts to 15625 parameters. However, I cannot figure out the way this is calculated. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: 5 to the 6th power is 15625, and a standard 4th-order polynomial curve has 5 parameters - might this be related to what you had read?

Comment: It was an example in a slide deck on polynomial linear regression (and overfitting in this case). I also figured out that 5^6 is 15625, however, I couldn't come up with why it would be 5^6 when it says 4th order polynomial in 5 dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems like too many by quite a lot (a couple of orders of magnitude).

First, let's break down what we are counting.

Let's be concrete and name things: our variables are $v, w, x, y$, and $z$.  A completely general fourth order polynomial contains individual terms of every degree from zero through four.  So:

$$y, \ xz, \ v^2 x z, \ y^3 z, \ w^4$$

are examples of terms in our potential polynomial.  A general polynomial regression of this kind will estimate a parameter for each of these individual terms.  So to calculate how many parameters are estimated, we can calculate the number of terms in a general polynomial in five variables with degree four.

Let me introduce the star and bars game.  Suppose you have a row of five stars:

```
* * * *
```

And I ask you to draw four bars between the stars.  You can draw bars to the left or right of all the stars, you can draw as many bars between two stars as you wish, and you have to use all the bars.  Here are some example outcomes:

```
* | * | * | * |
|||| * * * *
* | * | | * * |
```

Associate to each outcome of the stars and bars game a polynomial term like so:

```
- The number of stars before the first bar is the power of $v$.
- The number of stars between the first and second bar is the power of $w$. 
- The number of stars between the second and third bar is the power of $x$. 
- The number of stars between the third and fourth bar is the power of $y$. 
- The number of stars after the final bar is the power of $z$
```

So for example:

```
* | * | * | * |  -> v w x y
|||| * * * *     -> v^4
* | * | | * * |  -> v w y^2
```

You should easily convince yourself that each fourth degree term is associate with exactly one outcome.  Therefore, to count the number of fourth degree polynomials in five variables, you can instead count the number of outcomes of this star and bar game.

I can think of this as: I have $n + k$ places to put *something*, which can be either a bar or a star.  I place n stars in some of the places, and then k bars in the remaining

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ -> * _ * _ * _ * _  -> * | * | * | * |
```

This means that there are:

$$ {n + k}\choose{k} $$

outcomes to the stars and bars game.

To get the answer you're after, we use this method to count the number of fourth degree terms, third degree terms, second degree terms, first degree terms, and zeroth degree terms, and then sum:

$$ {{4 + 4}\choose{4}} + {{4 + 3}\choose{3}} + {{4 + 2}\choose{2}} + {{4 + 1}\choose{1}} + {{4 + 0}\choose{0}} $$

In python:

```
In [1]: from scipy.special import binom

In [2]: sum(binom(4 + k, k) for k in [4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
Out[2]: 126.0
```

So I believe the correct answer is 126 parameters.

Comment: They must have been counting combinations such as v^3 w^2 * x^4 * y^1 * z^2 is what I'm guessing.

Comment: Say they counted combinations, how would you calculate the number of parameters?

Comment: I do not know what method they used to determine the number of parameters.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as @JamesPhillips, I can't think of an interpretation that would lead to that answer.